# Placeholder strange behavior on input

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, placeholder

I'm programming an application for iPhone. My application has a login system. In the login system (and somewhere around my app) I have some placeholder in the UITextFields.

After a couple of months working on this app, I noticed a sudden problem that arose once. If I don't write in the text fields that have placeholders nothing happens, if I write something in them, the blue bar that blinks showing where you are in the text becomes very slow. Moreover the ScrollViews that I have become EXTREMELY slow. Some other strange behavior happens when I have a wheel that lets the user pick some choice: the options of the wheel "fall" from the sky while the user rolls it.

All of this happens only if I write something in a UITextField that has some placeholder. If not, nothing of this happens.

I know this sounds REALLY strange, I used a MacOSX program to create a video of the text field becoming slow.

It's `.swf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do one thing.. delete this textfiled and create a new one with different name and see is this problem occurring again? also try to set breakpoints in your code and debug your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried to add another UITextField and call the placeholder in another way, but still the error arises. I didn't create the object on my app though. I just wanted to see if the behavior was the same. The funny thing is that in this case the new UITextField even without placeholder has strange behavior. Could it be related to the view instead of the "placeholder"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't leaking any memory or running an endless loop on the cpu? Try monitoring your app with Instruments and check your cpu activity and memory allocations.

Comment: I tried to monitor it using the instrument for the Leaks, but I'm not really sure I can understand the output. The problem is: is it really a stupid placeholder that can start an infinite loop?

Comment: Monitor the app (running on your device) and add Leaks, Allocations and the Activity Monitor (or only the CPU Monitor) Simply check whether you encounter unusually high activity right after interacting with the textField.